# utilizando api do twitter com golang

Tags: oauth2, golang, twitter-api

Eu estou tentando fazer essa requisição "oauth/request_token" no twitter utilizando go.

```
// GET PARAMS TO REQUEST
t := time.Now().Format("20060102150405")
values := make(url.Values)
values.Add("oauth_nonce", auth.ANonce)
values.Add("oauth_callback", auth.Path)
values.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1")
values.Add("oauth_timestamp", t)
values.Add("oauth_consumer_key", auth.ClientID)

// GET SIGNATURE
baseString := fmt.Sprintf("POST&%s&%s", auth.Path, values.Encode())
key := fmt.Sprintf("%s&", auth.SecretID)

// GENERATE HASH
mac := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(key))
mac.Write([]byte(baseString))
signature := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(mac.Sum(nil))

// MAKE THE REQUEST
values.Add("oauth_version", "1.0")
values.Add("oauth_signature", signature)
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", auth.RequestToken, nil)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("getOAuthToken Request Error: %v", err)
}
// SET HEADER
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("OAuth oauth_nonce=\"%s\", oauth_callback=\"%s\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"%s\", oauth_consumer_key=\"%s\", oauth_signature=\"%s\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"", auth.ANonce, auth.Path, t, auth.ClientID, signature))
res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("getOAuthToken Client Error: %v", err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()
```

O problema é que eu estou recebendo esse erro:

> {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

Qual seria o problema com o meu codigo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código possui uma diversidade de problemas!
O primeiro é que você está usando `t` com um formato incorreto. O formato esperado para **oauth_timestamp** é timestamp em segundos. Veja a diferença:

```
//erro #1
t := time.Now().Format("20060102150405")
fmt.Println("time: ", t)

//correto #1
t_ := fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().Unix())
fmt.Println("time: ", t_)
```

Veja no playground: https://play.golang.org/p/L74MzEHkVwS

Outro erro é que você não está seguindo os passos para a construção da coleção dos parametros. Na documentação diz:

> The process to build the string [for Collecting parameters] is very
>   specific:
>
> 1. Percent encode every key and value that will be signed.
> 2. Sort the list of parameters alphabetically [1](https://play.golang.org/p/ZYvOfQZBMS5) by encoded key [2].
> 3. For each key/value pair:
> 4. Append the encoded key to the output string.
> 5. Append the "=" character to the output string.
> 6. Append the encoded value to the output string.
> 7. If there are more key/value pairs remaining, append a ‘&’ character to
>      the output string.

Observe alguns pontos importantes neste passo:

1. Você deve fazer o encode na chave e no valor;
2. Você deve ordenar a chave

Isto quer dizer que ao invés de você usar um `url.Values()` você deveria ter feito algo como:

```
values := make(map[string]string)
values["oauth_nonce"] = auth.ANonce
values["oauth_callback"] = auth.Path
values["oauth_signature_method"] = "HMAC-SHA1"
values["oauth_timestamp"] = t
values["oauth_consumer_key"] = auth.ClientID
values["oauth_version"] = "1.0" //include here
//encode each key/value, sort key and build string
params := sortedParams(values)
```

De posse dos parâmetros você deve produzir a base para a assinatura. Neste ponto você comete mais dois erros:

1. Você não codifica a url da requisição e
2. Você não codifica os parâmetros coletados.

Na documentação diz:

> To encode the HTTP method, base URL, and parameter string into a
>   single string:
>
> 1. Convert the HTTP Method to uppercase and set the output string equal
>      to this value.
> 2. Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
> 3. Percent encode the URL and append it to the output string.
> 4. Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
> 5. Percent encode the parameter string and append it to the output
>      string.
>
> Make sure to percent encode the parameter string! The signature base
>   string should contain exactly 2 ampersand ‘&’ characters.

Assim sendo você deveria fazer:

```
//build signature base
baseString := fmt.Sprintf("POST&%s&%s", 
    url.QueryEscape(auth.RequestToken), //here is request token url
    url.QueryEscape(params))
```

Antes de fazer a requisição você comete mais dois erros, você remove `oauth_version` dos parâmetros iniciais e não codifica a assinatura. E este passo é feito tanto na inclusão da assinatura aos parâmetros quando no header do request. Veja:

> The signing key is simply the percent encoded consumer secret,
>   followed by an ampersand character ‘&’[...]

Dessa forma você deverá fazer algo assim:

```
values["oauth_signature"] = url.QueryEscape(signature)
header := fmt.Sprintf(`OAuth oauth_nonce="%s", ...`,
        url.QueryEscape(auth.ANonce), 
        url.QueryEscape(auth.Path), 
        url.QueryEscape(t), 
        url.QueryEscape(auth.ClientID), 
        url.QueryEscape(signature))
```

Removendo esses erros você irá resolver seu problema!
Link para as referências:

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/percent-encoding-parameters
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes
- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token

Eu testei seu código e deixei no [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZYvOfQZBMS5) para um melhor entendimento.

Espero tê-lo ajudado!

Comment: Cara excelente as dicas que você me deu e por ter feito essa explicação detalhada, nem sei como agradecer. Felizmente eu ja tinha conseguido resolver os problemas a alguns dias atras, apos muito quebrar a cabeça e ler e re-ler a documentação da API, mas vejo que com essas suas dicas ainda tenho coisas a melhorar no meio código haha. **Muito obrigado** mesmo, vou deixar o link aqui do meu codigo caso você queira dar uma olhada tbm: [github_twitterapi](https://github.com/sampalm/golangWebTraining/tree/master/00_hands-on/10_oauth/04_twitter)

Comment: Vi seu código! Realmente ainda precisa de cuidados com a documentação. Tente seguir exatamente o que se pede. Uma outra sugestão é criar seu próprio encode. Nunca testei, mas já ouvi dizer que há casos em que o url.QueryEscape não retorna o resultado correto. Enfim, sucesso!